# Sort JSON table alphabetically and by value on a second level

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I want to sort the jJSON table alphabetically AND on a second level by the value of data.fuelState (float). I managed to get the alphabetically sorting done (thanks stackoverflow :)) .. How has this to be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<table class="table table-condensed" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link">Die Übersicht zu Drive-Now München lädt... Bitte einen Moment Geduld!</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function callJSON() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            $ ("#usertable").empty();
            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); });
            /*cars.sort(function(a,b) {
            return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);
             });*/
               $.each(cars, function(key, data){
              /*  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var Anfang = new google.maps.LatLng(48.158572777778, 11.581866944444);
                var Ende = new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude);
                var request = {
                    origin: Anfang,
                    destination: Ende,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
                };
                var def = $.Deferred();

                var dur = 's';

                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        dur = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                        console.log(dur);
                    }
                    def.resolve();
                    });

                console.log(dur);*/
                var laenge=cars.length;
                var vint=data.vin;
                var coopers="";
                var tanken="";
                var drive="MAN";
                var fuelfarbe="#01DF3A";
                var prozent="%";
                var kosten=" 31 Cent/Min "
                var tanksymbol="glyphicon-tint";
                var farbe="success";
                var flugbadge="";
                var ortbadge="glyphicon-map-marker";
                var v=vint.substring(3,7);
                if(v=="SX31"){coopers=" S";}
                if(v=="SW71"){coopers=" SD";}
                if(data.model=="BMW ActiveE "){tanksymbol="glyphicon-flash";}
                if(data.model=="BMW X1 "){kosten=" 34 Cent/Min ";}
                if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="AUT";}
                if((48.347910654607695 < data.position.latitude && data.position.latitude < 48.35988839686733)&&(11.781678199768066 < data.position.longitude && data.position.longitude < 11.792492866516113)){flugbadge="<span class='badge'>+12€</span>"; ortbadge="glyphicon-plane";}
                if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken="20 Freiminuten für Vollbetankung"; farbe="warning";}
                $('#usertable').append(
                    function() {
                        return "<tr class="+farbe+">"+
                                    "<td>"+data.model+coopers+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> "+data.carName+"</td>"+
                                    //"<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> "+dur+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+drive+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+tanksymbol+"'></span>" +data.fuelState+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.licensePlate+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon "+ortbadge+"'></span> "+data.address+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></span>"+kosten+flugbadge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+laenge+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><a href='https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin="+ data.vin +"'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs' type='button'>Reservieren</button></a></td>"+

                                    //"<td><img src='"+data.model+"1.png'/></td>"+
                                "<tr>"; 
                    }
                );
            })
        }).always(callJSON);
    }, 2000);
    }
    $(callJSON);
    });
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '..', '..');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is a JSON table? Do you mean you want to sort data in an array derived from a JSON string before populating a table with the data?  Have you made an attempt to implement this second level of sorting?

Comment: cars.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);});

Comment: Above: This is the standalone sorting for this value. I dont know how to implement this for a second level sort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add your secondary sorting logic inside of the "==" case for your primary sorting parameter.

```
var lst = [
    {a:"abc", b:{c:1.5}},
    {a:"abcd", b:{c:1.4}},
    {a:"abcd", b:{c:1.6}},
    {a:"abc", b:{c:1.3}}
];
lst.sort(function(x, y) {
    if(x.a == y.a) {
        if(x.b.c == y.b.c) {
            return 0;
        } else if(x.b.c < y.b.c) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else if(x.a < y.a) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
for(var k in lst) {
    console.log(lst[k].a + " " + lst[k].b.c);
}
```

Comment: Im a bloddy beginner :) ... I have cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); });
AND cars.sort(function(a,b) {return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState); I dont get it how to add my second sorting locig into the first one ...
             });

Comment: @user2718017 - You only need 1 call to cars.sort and the sort function needs to be formatted like my example above. In the case of my example x.a and y.a would represent your el1.model and el2.model, while my x.b.c and y.b.c would represent your a.fuelState and b.fuelState.

Comment: cars.sort(function(el1, el2) {
      if(el1.model== el2.model) {
          if(a.fuelState == b.fuelState) {
            return 0;
         } else if(a.fuelState < b.fuelState) {
            return -1;
         } else {
            return 1;
         }
      } else if(el1.model < el2.model) {
         return -1;
      } else {
         return 1;
      }
   });

Comment: Ok i got it now ... Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON into a JavaScript object (JSON.parse):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Then sort whatever field that needs to be sorted using the array prototype sort.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

---

It looks like JQuery does the parsing for you - I didn't notice it was JQuery initially. I tend to use the `$` variable for my own libraries.

Comment: My Problem is, that i dont get it how to put the second logic into the first one .... I have cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); }); AND cars.sort(function(a,b) {return parseFloat(b.fuelState) - parseFloat(a.fuelState);